# How to block highlighting of certain nicks in ERC?

Tags: faces, erc

Some people in IRC channels I frequent have elected to use extremely common words for their nicks, including "a" and "me". I use `erc-hl-nicks`, and was able to block those particular nicks from getting colored, but I would like to block them from being **bolded** as well. It seems it's ERC's default behavior to **bold** nicks when they are mentioned. See the attached screenshots, where "a" and "D" are highlighted in bold.

How can I indicate to ERC that those nicks should not be bolded or highlighted? I've played around with the `erc-fools` list, but I can't get that to do anything, and every time I turn it on, it breaks nick coloring for most people.

[image]

Comment: Here is a link to the library at issue:  https://github.com/leathekd/erc-hl-nicks/blob/master/erc-hl-nicks.el

Comment: @lawlist I'm not sure that's the library at issue. I've told it to block those nicks, and they no longer get colored as they used to. I think ERC's default behavior is to bold nicks, is it not?

Comment: If you get this behaviour with erc without any plugins, then it would be better to have a screenshot without the plugin.

Comment: If you disable the library `erc-hl-nicks`, do you still get a highlighting of `a` and `D` and if you place your cursor at either of those points and type `C-u C-x =`, do you get a description of using `erc-nick-default-face`?  If not, what face do you see?

Comment: I disabled `erc-hl-nicks` and `a` and `D` were still highlighted. And the description did indeed say `erc-nick-default-face`.

Comment: I'm keen to get this myself, somebody with the annoying username `so` hangs out in the haskell room... I think the logic is in `erc-match.el` but I can't be sure.

Comment: Somewhere there must be a list of nicknames. Can you filter that before a matching expression is created from it?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off bolding of all nicknames quite easily. Use `M-x customize` then look for the face that you've discovered already, `erc-nick-default-face`, then unclick the "bold".

This is a bit drastic unless you're using an addon like the package you've found. It feels a bit heavyweight to me to have a package just for highlighting usernames.

However, I'd like to be able to tell ERC to just not highlight nicks shorter than 3 characters, or ideally have a banlist... but I can't figure out how to do that.